# URL rewrite using htaccess and virtual subfolders

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got this in htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^records$ records.php [L]
RewriteRule ^records/$ records.php [L]
RewriteRule ^records/pro$ records_pro.php [L]
RewriteRule ^records/pro/$ records_pro.php [L]
Rewriterule ^records/pro/player/(.*?).html$ records_mpro.php?name=$1 [L]
Rewriterule ^records/pro/map/(.*?).html$ records_mapro.php?map=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^records/pro/totales$ records_qpro.php [L]
RewriteRule ^records/pro/totales/$ records_qpro.php [L]
```

Everything works fine execpt the `/records` and `/records/` rewrite

Any ideas? I can't make it work

Comment: The rules look correct. What does it do wrong? 404?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one please. And be sure `records.php` is same directory with `htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

Rewriterule ^records/pro/player/(.*?).html$ records_mpro.php?name=$1 [L]
Rewriterule ^records/pro/map/(.*?).html$ records_mapro.php?map=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^records/pro/totales(/?)$ records_qpro.php [L]
RewriteRule ^records/pro(/?)$ records_pro.php [L]
RewriteRule ^records(/?)$ records.php [L]
```